# Windows 8 - Enable Remote access option gone

Tags: windows-8

I installed win 8 rtm on my laptop and today decided i wanted to RDP to it. I went to the remote table of the 'system properties' dialog and theres no option to enable it. There's a useless 'remote assistance' fieldgroup that microsoft apparently want to force me to use.

What I want is the magic checkbox that lets anyone RDP in. I've seen (http://blogs.technet.com/b/digital_musketeer/archive/2011/09/14/how-to-enable-remote-desktop-on-the-windows-8-ctp.aspx) other people have the option but I don't. Mine looks like the screenshot in the link except the remote access field group isn't there. I am an admin. Anyone know the reg key to turn this on?

Comment: Which Windows 8 edition are you using, and is it activated?

Comment: It was activated. I did consider the edition but could not remember what I installed. The My Computer screen just said "Windows 8".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions#Comparison_chart only the Pro and Enterprise versions of Windows 8 can host RDP. So if you don't have any of those versions you will not be able to connect to you laptop using RDP. Also confirmed on the offical Windows team blog at http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/bloggingwindows/archive/2012/04/16/announcing-the-windows-8-editions.aspx.

I'm running the Windows 8 Enterprise RTM and I can get the same dialog as in your linked blog post. There are slightly different choices but the options are there, see http://www.guidingtech.com/13469/how-to-enable-remote-desktop-in-windows-8/ for screenshots of the dialog in Win8 RTM.

Comment: Thanks, I think I can change the product key via the My Computer win.

Comment: +1 Didn't realize that I had used a Retail Key (instead of Pro)... never would have thought of this.